# HTML align text to right in wordpress contact 7 plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I align the following to right (I want it to be RTL)

```
<div class="grid pixcode--grid">
  <div class="grid__item  six-twelfths palm-one-whole">
  [text* your-name placeholder "שם פרטי"]
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item  six-twelfths palm-one-whole">
  [text* last-name placeholder "שם משפחה"]
  </div>
</div>
<div>
[tel* tel-594 placeholder = "טלפון"]
</div>
[email* your-email placeholder "אימייל"] [textarea your-message placeholder "הודעה"][submit "שלח"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
.wpcf7-form { direction:rtl; text-align: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

```
div {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

in your css (add appropriate class)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

css:

```
div .grid_item{
   direction: rtl;
   text-align: right;
}
```

Hope it works.